# Date Time Formats in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, datetime-format

What are these date-time formats? I need to convert them to the same format, to check if they are the same. These are just two coming from a separate data source, so I need to find a way to make them the same format. Any ideas?

- **2013-07-12T07:00:00Z**
- **2013-07-10T11:00:00.000Z**

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is probably a more elegant solution but if its a string just cut out the extra .000

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt

Comment: If you find any answer helpful and it worked for you, then [kindly accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 65):

That extra `.000` is micro seconds.

This will convert a date string of a format to datetime object.

```
import datetime
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-07-12T07:00:00Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-07-10T11:00:00.000Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

Then convert them into any format depending on your requirement, by using:

```
new_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
d1.strftime(new_format)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful - it works. How do I reverse it, as well? So I can turn d1 or d2 back into their original datetime formats. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1579970  `"2013-07-12T07:00:00Z"` is a string and d1is a datetime object. You can convert a datetime object to a string in any format you want using `strftime()` . So in this case you would do `d1.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") `

Comment: @user1579970 Kindly close the question by [accepting the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it worked for you.

Comment: Thank u so much <3

Answer (score 12):

perhaps use `.isoformat()`

> string in ISO 8601 format, YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS[.mmmmmm][+HH:MM]

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + "Z"
'2013-07-11T22:26:51.564000Z'
>>>
```

*`Z` specifies "zulu" time or UTC.*

You can also add the timezone component by making your datetime object *timezone aware* by applying the appropriate *tzinfo* object.  With the *tzinfo* applied the `.isoformat()` method will include the appropriate utc offset in the output:

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> d.isoformat()
'2019-11-11T00:52:43.349356+00:00'
```

You can remove the *microseconds* by change the *microseconds* value to `0`:

```
>>> no_ms = d.replace(microsecond=0)
>>> no_ms.isoformat()
'2019-11-11T00:52:43+00:00'
```

Also, as of *python 3.7* the `.fromisoformat()` method is available to load an iso formatted datetime string into a python datetime object:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2019-11-11T00:52:43+00:00')
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 11, 0, 52, 43, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt

Comment: So how do we parse dates with +00:00 on the end prior to 3.7 ?  %z fails....

Answer (score 5):

you can try to trim the string

```
data = "2019-10-22T00:00:00.000-05:00"
result1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(data[0:19],"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
result2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(data[0:23],"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
result3 = datetime.datetime.strptime(data[0:9], "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 3):

use datetime module.

For a variable

```
import datetime
def convertDate(d):
     new_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(d,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
     return new_date.date()
convertDate("2019-12-23T00:00:00.000Z")
```

you can change the ".date()" to ".year", ".month", ".day" etc...

Output: # is now a datetime object

```
datetime.date(2019, 12, 23)
```

For a DataFrame column, use apply()

```
df['new_column'] = df['date_column'].apply(convertDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

*** Short and best way:**

```
str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(' ','T')
or
str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(' ','T') + "Z"
```