# how can i make timestamp date to be like D/M/Y and the hour (20:00) in my embed? instead of just now and 20:00 (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

this is my code

> ```
> @bot.hybrid_command()
> @commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
> async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
>     await member.kick(reason=reason)
>     await ctx.reply(f'{member.name} foi expulso do servidor.', ephemeral=True)
>     channel = bot.get_channel(WINTON_STATUS)
>     embed = discord.Embed(
>         title=f'{member.global_name} kikou pros crias',
>         description=f'{member.mention}',
>         timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(),
>         color=0x2b4982,
>     )
>     
>     await channel.send(embed=embed)
> ```
>
> i want it to look like this [the way that i want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Cux.png)
>
> but it looks like this [the way that it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsuMs.png)

I tried to put different things instead of 'now' but I have no idea what to put

Comment: It's called `datetime` formatting. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594298/date-time-formats-in-python

Answer (score 0):

As @MSH pointed out in their comment: You can use `datetime` formatting.

In your case, you are probably looking for something like the following:

```py
datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y | %H:%M')
```

If you want to know what the different directives mean, check out the Python documentation about [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime)

For a more detailed overview, and other possibilities, take a look at the following page: [Date and Time Format](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cmofm/9.0.0?topic=SSEPCD_9.0.0/com.ibm.ondemand.mp.doc/arsa0257.html)